# Extract a YYYmmDD in PHP

Tags: php, string, datetime

I have images and videos from my camera which are uploaded to my server. In order to properly organize them I need to extract the year month and day. But I cant seem to get this pregmatch right..

Input would be 20211215_083437.jpg
Output would be Year2021 Month11 Day15

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/', $value, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[0];
    $month = $matches[2];
    $day = $matches[3];
```

Comment: Remove `$` from the end of the pattern, and `$year` is `$matches[1];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` anchor in your RegEx to make it work: it matches the end of the string but yours has content after the date.
Also, the year is the 1st capture group. The index `0` contains the complete matching string.

```php
if (preg_match('/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/', $value, $matches)) {
    $year = $matches[1];
    $month = $matches[2];
    $day = $matches[3];
}
```

But, using a regex for this is overkill. You could sustract the date part of the filename and create a `DateTime` object from it:

```php
$date_string = substr($value, 0, 8);

$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $date_string);

// Format the date as you want
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: The DateTime constructor will actually handle Ymd format directly, by the way, so `$date = new DateTime(substr($value, 0, 8));` will also work

Answer (score 0):

With DateTime::createFromFormat the expression can be completely parsed. substr is not needed. The expression after the underscore stands for a time I think.

```
$str = '20211215_083437.jpg';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd_His.???', $str);

var_dump($dt);
//object(DateTime)#2 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2021-12-15 08:34:37.000000" ..

echo $dt->format('\Y\e\a\rY \M\o\n\t\hm \D\a\yd');
```